# Change colors to the 'fill' in aes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this:

```
colr=c(a='black',b='red',c='brown')
```

Basically, i have used the fill with the categories from a column in the df in the `aes`. Thus it will show through the categories the plot. The problem is when i try to put the `colr` vector in the `fill` to change colors as it says it encounters the problem

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5): fill
```

Obviously the incorrect way of typing it makes it think that the colors refer to the `brands`column while it should refer to the `g_classes` in the `fill`.

```
 ggplot(df,aes(brands,fill=g_classes))+geom_bar(stat='count',fill=colr)
```

So, how to pass the colors in the `colr` vector to the `fill` (g_classes) in `aes`?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example because without a reproducible example it is difficult to test your code. Just based on your description, please look into `scale_fill_manual` (http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html). Here is also a good reference: (http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an option to use the `scale_fill_manual` command. It has to be the same length as you have categories, however. In this case it seems that you are attempting to specify three colours for five categories, and this is most likely why your code fails.

It is hard to reproduce your problem given the limited examples you give, but try omitting the `fill` argument in the `geom_bar` command, and changing the value for the `stat` argument to "identity"

Change your colour vector to

```
colr=c("black","red","brown")
```

and add additional ggplot line

```
scale_fill_manual(values=colr)+
```

Comment: i want the colr to be applied on the classes on the fill. not the df.What you wrote didn't correct it

Comment: Much of my answer is based on speculation (I assume a, b, and c are the names of the groups?). I would need a reproducible example in order to help you further.

Comment: ok thanks i did it without the breaks and put the vector in the values in the first form without the variable and it worked also the pdfs form the other guy helped a lot.

Comment: I made a correction to your code to show the version that did work. You have to put the vector as it is and not the variable.Which is like the same but if you put the variable it doesn't show anything.Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Right, i see a typo there in the code actually (missing "). This is what happens when it isn't given a test-run beforehand, i suppose. ;) Whether you write it in manually or pass a pre-saved vector should not matter.